# Fitting CauchyDistribution to data list to determine peak

Tags: fitting, peak-detection

I have a list of data in the form like this {{-3,12},{-3.01,13.4},{-3.04,13.6},...} where the x value is time and the y value is current.

FindPeak gives me peaks for everydata point i have and FindFit doenst give me the right value, which i estimate by looking at the listlineplot of the dataset.

Any tips on how to put a CauchyDistribution over my list or how to find the peaks, which there should be 2 of. the rest is just background noise and is 3-10mV while the peaks are at 80mV and should follow a Cauchy Distribution.

Thank you very much for any tips... I have been looking through the internet for the last 3 hours trying to find a solution to this...

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without the data, a plot of the data, or even any code, but a common issue with fitting is not providing any constraints. If you have two peaks, you should take the sum of two Cauchy distributions, and constrain as many parameters as possible. Also, if you have current vs. time, the area under the curve is probably not 1, so you'll need to add a scaling parameter like `NonlinearModelFit[{a1 PDF[CauchyDistribution[b1, c1], t] + a2 PDF[Cauchy Distribution[b2, c2], t], {0 < a1, 0 < a2, min1 < b1 < max1, max1 < b2 < max2, 0 < c1, 0 < c2}}, {a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2}, t]`.

Comment: @MassDefect Thank you very much for your help already =)

Comment: It seems like i cant put boundaries on my parameters this way, since mathematica then just returns what was written?!(i added the data list and gave max1/max2 and min1 values)

Comment: I will now divide my data into 2 parts that each contain a peak so this works. What really helped was adding parameters do the plain Cauchy Distribution. So thank you very very much for that. Was stuck a long time. 
So no need to answer about this question anymore!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped a bit! In principle you should be able to fit both peaks with something similar to what I wrote (though it looks like I made at least one mistake), but if the current method works for you, then that's good too!

Comment: Perhaps @EisKekks can offer a self answer? It would be valuable to see the final result!

Comment: Just to make things clear:  you are attempting to fit a curve with the same shape as a Cauchy probability density other than maybe a shift (adding in an intercept) and a multiple of the Cauchy probability density.  That is a "regression" problem and not fitting a Cauchy distribution from a random sample from some (maybe Cauchy) distribution.